# .erb equivalent to the PHP $_GET["name"];

Tags: ruby, erb

I have a page set up in PHP which pulls data from the URL and echos it in HTML. Is there a .erb Ruby equivalent to this?

```
<?php echo $_GET["name"];?>
```

Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Is the question "how to access query parameters"? Because that is outside the scope of ERB .. which web-framework is being used?

Comment: Ah I see. Yes, that's right. We're using RoR

Answer (score 0):

In ERB, it looks like this:

```
<%= variable_name %>
```

If you want to perform some action without printing the result, you do this

```
<% @user.sign_up %>
```

Notice the difference being the `=`

Comment: Do you know how to print a variable taken from the URL? For example, when going to something like sitename.com/video.php?name=abc, it would set a variable with the string 'abc', and print that onto the page?

Comment: That will be a part of the params hash: <%= params[:name] %>